# Как подружить jQuery and Prototype?

Tags: jquery, prototype

1. Как подружить jquery and prototype?
2. Почему может скрипт прототайпа не только в ИЕ9? У меня есть окно с формой, вод код JS:

-

```
var Siteusers = Class.create();
Siteusers.prototype = {
    initialize: function () {
        this.updatePrivateMsgCnt();
    },
    toFriend: function () {
        this.getFriendsForm();
    },
    sendToFriend: function () {
        $('toFriendsContent').hide();
        $('toFriendLoader').show();
        $('rLink').value = location.href;
        var form = $('sendToFriendForm');
        var els = form.getInputs('text');
        els.each(function (el) {
            if ($('_' + el.readAttribute('name'))) {
                $('_' + el.readAttribute('name')).hide();
            }
        });
        $('_rComment').hide();
        news_content('');
        new Ajax.Request(form.action, {
            method: 'post',
            parameters: form.serialize(),
            onSuccess: function (t) {
                var responseData = eval(t.responseText);
                if (responseData != true && responseData.length > 0) {
                    responseData.each(function (errStr) {
                        var _data = errStr.split(/:/);
                        if ($('_' + _data[0])) {
                            Event.observe($('_' + _data[0]), 'mouseover', function (e) {
                                news_content(_data[1]);
                                $('news_an_popup').style.display = 'block';
                                Event.observe($('_' + _data[0]), 'mousemove', function (e) {
                                    follower1(e);
                                });
                            });
                            Event.observe($('_' + _data[0]), 'mouseout', function (e) {
                                news_content('');
                                $('news_an_popup').style.display = 'none';
                            });
                            $('_' + _data[0]).show();
                        }
                    });
                    $('toFriendLoader').hide();
                    $('toFriendsContent').show();
                } else {
                    $('toFriendLoader').hide();
                    $('toFriendsContent').hide();
                    $('toFriendsSuccMsg').show();
                }
            }
        });
    },
    getFriendsForm: function () {
        docscr = (self.pageYOffset || (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || (document.body && document.body.scrollTop)) + 20;
        $('to_friends').style.top = docscr + 'px';
        $('to_friends').style.display = 'block';
        $('toFriendLoader').show();
        $('toFriendsContent').update('');
        new Ajax.Request('/siteusers?action=_get_send_to_friend_form', {
            method: 'get',
            onSuccess: function (t) {
                $('toFriendsContent').update(t.responseText);
                $('toFriendsContent').show();
                $('toFriendLoader').hide();
            }
        });
    },
    showPersonalMsgForm: function (sender, toId) {
        docscr = (self.pageYOffset || (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) || (document.body && document.body.scrollTop)) + 20;
        $('privateMsg').style.top = docscr + 'px';
        $('privateMsg').style.display = 'block';
        $('privateMsgLoader').show();
        $('privateMsgContent').update('');
        new Ajax.Request('/siteusers?action=_get_private_msg_form', {
            method: 'get',
            onSuccess: function (t) {
                $('privateMsgContent').update(t.responseText);
                $('toId').value = toId;
                $('privateMsgContent').show();
                $('privateMsgLoader').hide();
            }
        });
    },
    sendPrivateMsg: function () {
        $('privateMsgContent').hide();
        $('privateMsgLoader').show();
        var form = $('personalMsgForm');
        var els = form.getInputs('text');
        els.each(function (el) {
            if ($('_' + el.readAttribute('name'))) {
                $('_' + el.readAttribute('name')).hide();
            }
        });
        $('_rComment').hide();
        news_content('');
        new Ajax.Request(form.action, {
            method: 'post',
            parameters: form.serialize(),
            onSuccess: function (t) {
                var responseData = eval(t.responseText);
                if (responseData != true && responseData.length > 0) {
                    responseData.each(function (errStr) {
                        var _data = errStr.split(/:/);
                        if ($('_' + _data[0])) {
                            Event.observe($('_' + _data[0]), 'mouseover', function (e) {
                                news_content(_data[1]);
                                $('news_an_popup').style.display = 'block';
                                Event.observe($('_' + _data[0]), 'mousemove', function (e) {
                                    follower1(e);
                                });
                            });
                            Event.observe($('_' + _data[0]), 'mouseout', function (e) {
                                news_content('');
                                $('news_an_popup').style.display = 'none';
                            });
                            $('_' + _data[0]).show();
                        }
                    });
                    $('privateMsgLoader').hide();
                    $('privateMsgContent').show();
                } else {
                    $('privateMsgLoader').hide();
                    $('privateMsgContent').hide();
                    $('privateMsgContentSuccMsg').show();
                }
            }
        });
    },
    updatePrivateMsgCnt: function () {
        if (siteuser_logged) {
            new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('hPersonalMsgCounter', '/siteusers?action=_updatePersonalMsgCnt', {
                method: 'get',
                frequency: 60,
                decay: 1
            });
        }
    }
};
var siteuser = null;

function initSiteusers() {
    siteuser = new Siteusers();
}
Event.observe(window, 'load', initSiteusers);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Пример с сайта:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Код использующий jQuery $ пишем здесь.
  });
  // Код использующий $ другой библиотеки пишем здесь.
</script>
```